# Entity Framework: Skip few columns or select as null from related entities

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have three entities as below

```
public partial class Ticket
{
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<TicketComment> TicketComments { get; set; }
}

public partial class TicketComment
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<CommentAttachment> CommentAttachments { get; set; }
    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
}

public partial class CommentAttachment
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int FileSize { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileContents { get; set; }  // holds large data

    public virtual TicketComment TicketComment { get; set; }
}
```

Here each Ticket can have multiple comments and each Comment can have 1 or 0 attachment.
I am trying to eager load all related entities for a given ticket with following code

```
var query = context.Tickets.Where(t => t.TicketId == ticketid)
             .Include(t => t.TicketComments.Select(c => c.CommentAttachments));
```

It is doing the job correctly.

Only the problem is that, it is also loading `byte[] FileContents`, which often has quite large data. I want to avoid it.

Is there any way i can select NULL for `FileContents` or skip this column at all?

I had tried with following

```
var query = context.Tickets.Where(t => t.TicketId == ticketid)
            .Include(t => t.TicketComments
                .Select(c => c.CommentAttachments
                    .Select(ca => new CommentAttachment()
                    {
                        CommentID = ca.CommentID,
                        FileContents = null,
                        FileId = ca.FileId,
                        FileName = ca.FileName,
                        FileSize = ca.FileSize
                    })));
```

But it is giving error

```
The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties. Parameter name: path
```

Any ideas to avoid loading `FileContents` column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class CommentAttachment
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int FileSize { get; set; }

    public virtual TicketComment TicketComment { get; set; }
}

public class FileContent
{
     FileContentId {get;set;}
     public int FileId { get; set; } // HERE IS THE FORGEIN KEY YOU HAVE TO UPDATE IT manually
     public byte[] FileContents { get; set; }  // holds large data
}
```

In this way you can load the FileContent only by need you have the CommentAttachment Id and you can include it any time.

Comment: This way i have to change model, it will also impact other areas of project. Is there no any way to achieve what i desired without modifying model?

Comment: Try this public byte?[] FileContents { get; set; } it might works.

Comment: I partially accept this answer because you suggest to modify Model. However it will take my model hierarchy to 4th level. Instead of adding 4th level hierarchy i modified model differently so it should remain on 3rd level.

Comment: We have the same problem; What you can also do create a custom stored procedure to retrieve the data from DB without the Streaming files this is no problem in EF 5 because it is supporting SP very good and it is easy to build in repository pattern or in your SW arichture . If you want I can show you an example I have a good example but the book is Germans.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a null getter but allowing setter to function in EF 6.0 and OData v4.

I've come across this same issue. The accepted answer is definitely a workable option and I almost implemented it today, but I was hoping to perform the task in code. My model differs slightly than what you have available in that a `byte[] Timestamp` column is available. Posting this workaround in the event that it can assist someone later.

For my case, the `byte[] FileContents` serves as a backup to a directory repository where we use the database to rebuild the directory structure and file contents if the front-end is wiped out for various reasons. So essentially we only POST/SET FileContents, we never read it through the front end program.

```
public partial class CommentAttachment
{
     //required for overriding get/set auto-property
     private byte[] _FileContents; 

     public int FileId { get; set; }
     public int CommentID { get; set; }
     public string FileName { get; set; }
     public int FileSize { get; set; }
     public byte[] FileContents 
     { 
          get
          {
               return Timestamp != null ? null : _FileContents;
          } 
          set
          {
               _FileContents = value;
          }
     }  // holds large data

     public virtual TicketComment TicketComment { get; set; }
     //Concurrency Token - triggered on create or update
     public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
 }
```

The above allowed our database table to stay the same, only the EF POCO changed. When creating a CommentAttachment record the `Timestamp` field is null/doesn't exist because it is triggered by the database; this allows _FileContents to be populated. When selecting a record, `Timestamp` is populated with a value from the database so `FileContents` is set to `null` to avoid querying the large data sets.

PUT/PATCH/POST works fine with this method when applied to OData v4 as well due to `Timestamp` not being passed for insert/update as it is a database triggered population.